# Multiple match rules in IDQ

Tags: match, transformation, informatica, fuzzy

I have to implement multiple match rules in IDQ in the following way:

```
First Name AND Last Name AND Gender -  All Exact
First Name AND Last Name AND (Mobile OR Phone) - All Exact
First Name AND Last Name - Fuzzy AND Email - Exact
```

What strategies (both for exact and fuzzy), I should apply in my Match transformation to implement the above match rules?

Comment: Could you please elaborate in detail?

Comment: 1) Do I have to create multiple mappings to implement all 3 sets of match rules? If no, should I have multiple match transformations in a single mapping?  2) In all 3 match rules, what attribute I should choose for a key generator? 3) What should be the match strategies while implementing these in Match transformation with weighing score and threshold value?